# AtTag mentions ios

Tags: ios

I am using STTweet label for display atTag mentions. My problem is want to mention last name along with mention. How can i do that?

Below post my code

```
 __block   CommentsTableViewCell *hashtag=self;
    labelCommenter_Comment.detectionBlock = ^(STTweetHotWord hotWord, NSString *string, NSString *protocol, NSRange range)
    {

        if ([string hasPrefix:@"#"] && [string length] > 1)
        {
            string = [string substringFromIndex:1];
            [hashtag hashTagDelegateCalling:string];
        }
        else if ([string hasPrefix:@"@"]  && [string length] > 1)
        {
            string = [string substringFromIndex:1];
            NSMutableString *atString = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",string];
            [arrayExp enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
             {

                 if ([[obj valueForKey:@"userName"] isEqualToString:atString]) {

                     NSString  *hashLinkValue = [obj valueForKey:@"hashLink"];
                     [hashtag atTheRateDelegateCalling:hashLinkValue];

                 }

             }];
        }

    };
```

Comment: Hi s bhai pls find this link,i think it will help you https://libraries.io/github/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel